# Overlapping Wizard pattern in Android (sharing Activities)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm considering the following design for my app activity flow:

Wizard 1:

```
MainMenuActivity-> Activity1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> Activity Final A
```

Wizard 2:

```
OtherActivity   -> Activity1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3 -> Activity Final B
```

So depeding where the wizard started I need to end with a different activity. Whats the best way of detecting the way?

Passing an extra along the activities in order to know the "launcher activity" at the Activity 3 is a nice method or have some kind of issue?

Thanks

Comment: passing it along as an extra seems like a fine solution to me.

Comment: It really depends what else there is you may need as a global state information. I prefer in more complex cases where I need to remeber also some variables, states, user inputs, etc to use either a class with static methods/variables or a singleton design. However if the origin is all you need then passing it all the way through is OK - I guess. As long as that's all.